# 40- iteration for the successive approximation

Tags: equation-solving

```
{
{u[n, 0]},
{u[n, 1]},
{u[n, 2]},
{u[n, 3]}
}
```

are unknown.

Initial conditions at `n = 0`,

```
{
{u[0, 0]},
{u[0, 1]},
{u[0, 2]},
{u[0, 3]}
} = {
{0.0625`},
{0.031249999999999997`},
{-0.0625`},
{-0.03125`}
};
```

Here the equations:

```
F1 := 0.04549512883486596` E^(-0.1` n) + 
10.` (-u[-1 + n, 0] + u[n, 0]) - 
7.071067811865475` (-u[-1 + n, 1] + u[n, 1]) - 
0.46266352733266075` u[n, 2] + 1.9629151055076721` u[n, 3] + 
7.071067811865477` (-u[-1 + n, 3] + u[n, 3])

F2 := -1.5454951288348655` E^(-0.1` n) + 
10.` (-u[-1 + n, 0] + u[n, 0]) + 
7.071067811865475` (-u[-1 + n, 1] + u[n, 1]) - 
11.047340291170295` u[n, 2] - 46.86989540377129` u[n, 3] - 
7.0710678118654435` (-u[-1 + n, 3] + u[n, 3])

F3 := u[n, 0] - u[n, 1] + u[n, 2] - u[n, 3]

F4 := u[n, 0] + u[n, 1] + u[n, 2] + u[n, 3]

sol = Table[
 Solve[{F1 == 0, F2 == 0, F3 == 0, F4 == 0}, {u[n, 0], u[n, 1], 
 u[n, 2], u[n, 3]}], {n, 1, 50}];
```

How to find the 40 iteration? i.e. `u[40,0]=?,u[40,1]=?,u[40,2]=?, u[40,3]=?`

Comment: Perhaps the down-voters could leave comments to help the poster improve their question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `RSolve`. Define your expressions:

```
F1 = 0.04549512883486596` E^(-0.1` n) + 10.` (-u[-1 + n, 0] + u[n, 0]) - 7.071067811865475` (-u[-1 + n, 1] + u[n, 1]) - 0.46266352733266075` u[n, 2] + 1.9629151055076721` u[n, 3] + 7.071067811865477` (-u[-1 + n, 3] + u[n, 3])
F2 = -1.5454951288348655` E^(-0.1` n) + 10.` (-u[-1 + n, 0] + u[n, 0]) + 7.071067811865475` (-u[-1 + n, 1] + u[n, 1]) - 11.047340291170295` u[n, 2] - 46.86989540377129` u[n, 3] - 7.0710678118654435` (-u[-1 + n, 3] + u[n, 3])
F3 = u[n, 0] - u[n, 1] + u[n, 2] - u[n, 3] 
F4 = u[n, 0] + u[n, 1] + u[n, 2] + u[n, 3]
```

Then

```
sol = FullSimplify[
  RSolve[{F1 == 0, F2 == 0, F3 == 0, F4 == 0, u[0, 0] == 0.0625`, 
    u[0, 1] == 0.031249999999999997`, u[0, 2] == -0.0625`, 
    u[0, 3] == -0.03125`}, {u[n, 0], u[n, 1], u[n, 2], u[n, 3]}, n]]
```

> {{u[n, 0] -> 
>      0.0113808 E^(-1.17352 n) + 0.0604988 E^(-0.1 n) - 
>       0.00937963 E^(-0.0664033 n),
>
> u[n, 1] -> 
>      0.00840294 E^(-1.17352 n) + 0.0207298 E^(-0.1 n) + 
>       0.00211726 E^(-0.0664033 n),
>
> u[n, 2] -> -0.0113808 E^(-1.17352 n) - 0.0604988 E^(-0.1 n) + 
>       0.00937963 E^(-0.0664033 n),
>
> u[n, 3] -> -0.00840294 E^(-1.17352 n) - 0.0207298 E^(-0.1 n) - 
>       0.00211726 E^(-0.0664033 n)}}

which gives you general formulas for all your `u[n, k]`. Evaluating at `n = 40`:

```
sol /. n -> 40
```

> {{u[40, 0] -> 0.000449444, u[40, 1] -> 0.000528352, 
>     u[40, 2] -> -0.000449444, u[40, 3] -> -0.000528352}}

Or you can create a `Table` of values with

```
Table[sol /. n -> k, {k, 1, 50}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much aardvark2012.

Comment: @Khaled Glad it helped. It's generally encouraged to [accept an answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if you feel it's adequately answered your question. That's not a request to accept _my_ question, I'm just not sure you're aware that you can do so. You may also find [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/asking) helpful.

Comment: @Khaled Thanks for the accept.